# Firebase vs BigQuery Active Users are not identical

Tags: google-bigquery

I have integrated firebase with bigquery to start reporting more insights about the application. First, I wanted to make sure the queries used in BigQuery are returning accurate result compared to Firebase Analytics Dashboard. I have tried the following query to count the active user in a day and found the numbers are different:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT user_pseudo_id ) AS Active_Users
FROM `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.events_20190419`
WHERE
  event_name IN ( 'user_engagement' )
```

In Firebase Dashboard, the number is 4870 whereas from BigQuery it is 4728. I have suspected the timezone but it is not the case. I have used:

```
  AND event_timestamp >= 1555534800000000  #+3GMT April 18, 2019 START
  AND event_timestamp <= 1555621200000000  #+3GMT April 18, 2019 END
```

in `WHERE` and span the `FROM` to multiple tables, yet, it is the same problem. I got the same exact number from BigQuery 4728 no matter what

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What does this query report? 

`SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT user_pseudo_id ) AS Active_Users
FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.events_20190419`

Comment: The timestamps you specified don't correlate to April 18, they are translated as: 04/17/2019 at 9:00pm (UTC) and 04/18/2019 at 9:00pm (UTC). Have you validated that the Firebase Dashboard shows the report within this time range?